# How to get selected object in kendo auto complete

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I have complex object list set as data source and need to get either selected object or selected field when item is selected in kendo auto complete.

For example, example provided at http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/autocomplete/data-binding/#toc-arrays-of-complex-data I need to get either full object back or the value of field value that is get "Alb" when "Albania" is selected.

Answer (score 1):

The AutoComplete component is designed to always keep the selected value as **string**. If you would like to get the selected data item, then I think you should use either the ComboBox or the DropDownList component. You can find more details in the `Value binding` documentation:

http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/autocomplete/value-binding/

Comment: It seems like we might need a text and value binding. I understand why the binding for value is the text, but there should be a way to get an id or other "lookup value" off of the object. Opening GitHub issue.

Comment: The AutoComplete component doesn't have notion for selected item or index. It also has details for one object field (valueField), which could lead to duplicate values/data items. It is unreliable to provide a selected data item in the Angular context (the 2-way binding).
I hope it is clearer now what the incentives behind the decision to work with primitive values only are (in the AutoComplete).

Comment: Plus one for a change to the api. There is an open feature request. http://kendoui-feedback.telerik.com/forums/555517-kendo-ui-for-angular-feedback/suggestions/19769149-autocomplete-selectionchange-event

Answer (score 1):

I did this by adding a template in the autocomplete and adding a click event like this:

```
     <kendo-autocomplete
                        #empList
                        [data]="EmployeeList"
                         [filterable]="true"
                       (filterChange)="handleFilter($event)"
                        valueField="DisplayName">
              <ng-template kendoAutoCompleteItemTemplate let-dataItem>
             <span class="k-state-default (click)="empSelected(dataItem)"">
{{dataItem.DisplayName }}</span><span class="ddlDept">
 ({{dataItem.DepartmentDescription }})</span>
          </ng-template>
        </kendo-autocomplete>
```

and then in the component I added a function to handle the click:

```
public empSelected(value: any): void {
    this.selectedEmployee = value;
}
```

Comment: This only works for click if you try enter it will not work as the enter event is stopped by the kendo component.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the selected item by filtering your original list of objects but the value returned.

So, taking the countries example you mention, you can get the selected country in the valueChange event. Then filter the list of countries by the country name.

It would look something like this:

```
let selectedArray = this.listItems.filter(function(el){
       return el['text'].toLowerCase().startsWith(event.toLowerCase());
       //return el.toLowerCase().indexOf(event.toLowerCase()) > -1;
     }) 
if(selectedArray.length>0){
  let selectedItem = selectedArray[0]
}
```

Once you have the selected item, you can get any data you want from it.

In your example, you would call

```
let shortName = selectedItem.value
```

In this way, when you select Albania, shortName will be set to 'Alb'

Comment: This is the best approach i have found so far myself. However, it is still not the best. The best would be to get access to the selection change event prior to the value change event like with other drop downs. Please check out the open feature request [http://kendoui-feedback.telerik.com/forums/555517-kendo-ui-for-angular-feedback/suggestions/19769149-autocomplete-selectionchange-event] and up vote.